# Changing the passwd file to reset password on Raspbian

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to reset the password of my Raspberry Pi 2 B running Raspbian, and I thought I could do this by mounting the sd card on my Ubuntu PC and change the shadow file for the pi user from

```
pi:[hash]: [...]
```

to

```
pi:*: [...]
```

in order to signify that my user doesn't have a password in shadow, just as it looks in Ubuntu when I remove my account's password with

```
sudo passwd my_user -d
```

However it didn't work and now I see I have on my Raspberry pi in /etc/ 2 passwd files and 2 shadow files: my modified files of passwd and shadow and a passwd- and shadow- file that seem to be the file versions, before I changed them.

Can someone please explain to me why this is happening? I'm more curious than frustrated with this.

Comment: Your command will set root password. Thy it from user prompt.

Comment: I tested it and my user didn't require a password afterwards, and I also user the command (w/o the -d option) to change my password to a 2 char password while testing stuff, because the normal passwd command forbid me to choose such a weak password. I think you mean `sudo passwd`

Answer (score 0):

whenever you run `passwd` to modify the shadow-database (which consists of the files `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`) it is making automatic backups of these files. the backups have `-` appended to the filename.

this is also true for other files managed by the same set of tools, e.g. `/etc/group`..

*this is normal*.

Comment: I guess, but when, and how is it triggered?